# Not to show the date before Present date Android DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Is there a way to not to show the dates/months before present date instead of disabling the dates in Android.

Comment: May i knw the solution ? code or link ?

Comment: setMinDate() with the current date time object via calendar

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with above answer :-

> ```
> Calendar c  = Calendar.getInstance();
>         c.set(2000,01,01);
> ```
>
> `datePicker.setMinDate(c.getTime().getTime());`

Using above lines datepickerdialog is not showing prevous date anymore with your datepicker dialog.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Try changing the month in the above code it will show up to January month of the year.But I want to hide dates/months before the present date.Hope you got it

Comment: then try as per this line :-c.set( System.currentTimeMillis()); @Manju

Comment: Both will be identically same will give the same result